# How to understand @Transactional with setters in Java?

Tags: java, spring, jpa, orm, spring-transactions

Following tutorial on Java Spring, I'm trying to understand how does @Transactional work with setters, and from other question/sources, I can't find a beginner-friendly explanation for it.

Let's say I have a user entity with getters and setters:

```
@Entity
public class User {
    // Id set up
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private String email;
    private String password;

    // Other constructors, setters and getters

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

And in the UserService I have a getUserName method:

```
@Service
public class UserService {
    private final UserRepository userRepository;

    @Autowired
    public UserService(UserRepository userRepository) {
        this.userRepository = userRepository;
    }

    @Transactional
    public void getUserName(Long id) {
        User user = userRepository.findById(id).orElseThrow();

        user.setName("new user name"); // Why will this update db?     
    }
}
```

With @Transactional annotated, the setter function does update db, is this the spring way of updating data? Can someone help explain in layman term, how the Transactional work with setters under the hood?

Edit:
Without `@Transactional`, setter function won't update db, but in
order to mutate db, will have to call `userRepository.save(user)`. And from [the video](https://youtu.be/9SGDpanrc8U?t=4929), the instructor simply says the Transactional will handle jpql for us, and use setters along with it to update db.

##### Resource update:

[Spring Transaction Management: @Transactional In-Depth](https://www.marcobehler.com/guides/spring-transaction-management-transactional-in-depth), hope this is helpful.

Comment: Why are you calling a setter method in `getName()`?  Note that for gets and simple sets, `@Transactional` is probably not needed at all.

Comment: It's just for testing purpose, I hit the endpoint with get request, and hard code the setName value. If I comment out `@Transactional`, the db never updates data. So, why dose setter and @Transactional updates db?

Comment: Your assumption is correct, `@Transactional` used for service methods which alters the data. So you must check that the `userRepository.findById` does change the data in database, if not `@Transactional` is not required.

Comment: @KarthikeyanVaithilingam `@Transactional` would only be needed in the case where the underlying SQL is more than a single statement.  For basic setters on a single table/entity, the underlying update should already be atomic.

Comment: @Karthikeyan Vaithilingam I am sure without `@Transactional`, db never updates, since I just queried it in db terminal..

Comment: Without the @Transactional spring will never commit any data in the database. Is required for insert/update/delete actions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, it is the underlying JPA provider (assume it is Hibernate) to be responsible for updating the entity but not Spring. Spring just provides the integration support with Hibernate.

To update an entity loaded from the DB , generally you need to make sure the following happens in order.

1. Begin a DB transaction
2. Use `EntityManager` to load the entity that you want to update.The loaded entity is said to be managed by this `EntityManager` such that it will keep track all the changes made on its state and will generate the necessary update SQL to update this entity in (4) automatically.
3. Make some changes to the entity 's state. You can do it through any means such as calling any methods on it , not just restricting to calling it by setter
4. Flush the `EntityManager`. It will then generate update SQL and send to DB.
5. Commit the DB transaction

Also note the followings:

- Spring provides `@Transactional` which is a declarative way to execute (1) and (5) by annotating it to a method.
- By default , Hibernate will call (4) automatically before executing (5) such that you do not need to call (4) explicitly.
- Spring Data JPA repository internally use `EntityManager` to load the user. So the user return from the repository will be managed by this EntityManager.

So in short , `@Transactional` is necessary to update the entity. And updating the entity is nothing to do with setter as it just care if there are state changes on the entity in the end , and you can do it without using setter.

Comment: As the name `@Transactional` indicates, is it correct that, upon the complete excution of the entire function, and as a result of any changes to the entity's state, all generated queries will be handled in one single transaction at step (5)?

Comment: And also, does the repository functions ( like `repository.findById()` ) invoke (2) step to load entity?

Comment: For both questions in your comments , you are right.

Answer (score 2):

Spring uses Hibernate as ORM under the hood.
When you call `userRepository.findById`, Hibernate entity manager is called under the hood, it retrieves entity from database and at the same time makes this `entity manageable` (you can read separately about Hibernate managed entities).
What it means, in a simple words, the Hibernate 'remembers' the reference to this entity in its internal structures, in the so-called `session`. It, actually, 'remembers' all entities which it retrieves from database (even the list of entities obtained by queries) during single transaction (in the very basic case).

When you make some method `@Transactional`, by default Hibernate `session` is `flushed` when such method is finished. `session.flush()` is called under the hood.

Once `session gets flushed`, Hibernate pushes all changes made to these `managed entities` back into the database.

That is why your changes got to the database, once method was finished, without any additional calls.

To dig deeper into the topic, you can read more about `Hibernate managed entities` , `session flush mode`, `repository.save(), repository.saveAndFlush() in Spring Data`.